# Newbie editor: caught between rock and

Tags: discussion

My edits need approval. Some are rejected :( or some are rejected by someone but finally accepted.

While "too minor" is easy to understand (but can be argued in some cases like incorrect code), I think case below is difficult:

> This edit changes too much in the original post; the original meaning or intent of the post would be lost.

Here is one edit that finally went through but one reviewer rejected it: https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/230107

My point in editing that question: I confess I guessed what OP meant and reworded accordingly. If one only looks by "extent" it would appear too much of editing but how can reviewer argue that "the original meaning or intent of the post would be lost"?

Is the criteria for rejection based on amount of "editing" rather than the actual result? So if an edit has a lot of rearrangement it should be rejected? Even though it may express things better?

In this exact case, how is the meaning or intent lost?

Comment: That's why it needs the approval of reject of 2.

Comment: Your edit was accepted. Also you only have had one rejected edit. 1 out of 41 suggested edits. Just keep up the work. I think I would have rejected your edit, but I cannot ignore that you are doing a good job with your edits.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think your edit was awesome, turning a badly written question with bad grammar into a well written question with good grammar.

However, what everyone has to learn to remember on SE, *you're on the internet*. Everyone here has their own opinion and not everyone agrees. I personally think there was no reason to reject your edit, someone else obviously did.  I know this can be terribly annoying (from personal experience), but it is something you have to learn to live with. This is why it takes either 2 approves or 2 rejects for an edit to get approved or rejected, to help make sure bad edits don't get approved and good edits don't get rejected on one person's opinion.

Overall your edits are very good, you only have one rejected. For comparison I had 14 rejected edits when I earned the edit privilege which is roughly 3 times the rejected edits you would have if you keep this ratio up.

So overall, you will have your rejected edits, everyone does, as long as they aren't getting close to your approved edits you're fine. If there was an edit of yours that got rejected that you *particularly* think ought to be approved you can drop in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) and ask for opinions.

Good luck and keep editing!

---

Here's a neat feature you might not have noticed. If you click the "more" link on the suggested edit's page:

[image]

It will expand to show you some interesting reviewer stats:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the kind words and encouragement!

Comment: "If there was an edit of yours that got rejected that you particularly think ought to be approved you can drop in chat and ask for opinions." That is a good suggestion to keep in mind; then maybe a high rep user can make the suggested edit.

Comment: Also, looking at the bottom picture @DKBose , you generally seem to have done OK with previous edits :D - more reputation makes not much difference until you [get past 2000 rep](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/edit), in which the edits on most things aren't reviewed.